# Regex: Capture cases where character is not within spaces

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I am trying to write a `regex` in order to capture the cases \ lines in which a specific, single character (in my case the equal sign, `'='`) is not within spaces.

Examples:

```
LABEL=SomeLabel    # -> should be captured: spaces missing from both sides
LABEL =SomeLabel   # -> should be captured: space missing from the right
LABEL= SomeLabel   # -> should be captured: space missing from the left
LABEL = SomeLabel  # -> should **NOT** be captured: spaces in both sides
```

I am actually quite bad at regex so sharing my attempts does not make much sense.
Plus, I have the feeling that this is a rather complex one...

Comment: I think using an alternation with an optional space would do `\w+ ?=\w+|\w+= \w+` https://regex101.com/r/G7cBtX/1

Comment: Do you want the matched text or just need to find if there is a match?

Comment: @AKSingh either way is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would combine zero-length assertion with alternative for this task as follows

```
import re
t1 = "LABEL=SomeLabel"
t2 = "LABEL =SomeLabel"
t3 = "LABEL= SomeLabel"
t4 = "LABEL = SomeLabel"
pattern = r"(?<=\S)=|=(?=\S)"
print(bool(re.search(pattern, t1)))
print(bool(re.search(pattern, t2)))
print(bool(re.search(pattern, t3)))
print(bool(re.search(pattern, t4)))
```

output

```
True
True
True
False
```

Explanation: `\S` denotes not-whitespace, we look for `=` preceded by non-whitespace (`(?<=\S)=`) or (`|`) `=` followed by whitespaces (`=(?=\S)`). Usage of zero-length assertion mean that solely `=` will be matched (not any adjacent character), for example `print(re.findall(pattern, t3))` output `['=']`. I used so-called raw-string to avoid need of extra escaping, for further discussion of this feature read [re docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. It works fine! Just a comment.. If you think of my example as a "truth table", it would seem that a solution with an **and** clause would be more appropriate than one with an **or**..